# Light-brown stripes on my Galaxy S6 Edge screen

Tags: broken-screen, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge for around 2 and a half months now. Since yesterday when having open a white screen (all white, such as a picture or some other menu) I see a 2 vague light-brown stripes.

[image]
[image]

I first thought it was some filth on my screen protector (ZAGG Invisible Shield), so I tried wiping it off, this didn't help anything.

There is always a thick-leather flipcase around my phone aswell.

I never dropped, made some damage, had some water-damage or dropped anything on this phone. It's in my pocket all the time without any heavy-weight stuff pushing onto it. The only thing I can think of is that I was holding something heavy against my pocket, but not 'laying it onto' my pocket, I was holding it myself.

What can this be and could it be a fixable issue?

Comment: Do the apps you most commonly use have a coloured area that lines up with the stripes? It seems a little soon to have screen burn-in, but it's worth ruling that out first.

Comment: @DanHulme  Not that I know of. That part of the screen is this usable though. This really sucks, I really hope this isn't that bad... Could it be my screen protector?

Comment: That seems unlikely. Your best bet might be to ask your local Samsung dealer: it could be a faulty screen, which they should replace for you.

Comment: @DanHulme I really hope so... Could there be some filth underneath the screen protector? And if that would be the case, how could that happen? As I said, what about the heavy weight I held? I didn't drop anything on it...